# IBM MobileFirst 8.0: Invalid Client Data error

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-runtime

We are migrating our hybrid apps to MobileFirst Server 8.0. While doing the same we are getting the following error message:

```
com.ibm.mfp.server.security.internal.context.ClientSecurityContextImpl error:93 FWLSE4050E: Invalid client data
Server Version: 8.0.2017070400
Cordova mf plugin version : 8.0.2017071211
```

Please, let us know what could be the possible reason.

The application is registered in MobileFirst Server and the version and app id exactly matches the config.xml entry.

Comment: Can you add a little more detail on how you are migrating the app to MobileFirst v8 ? Are you migrating a 7.1 Cordova project or a legacy hybrid project ?

Comment: Is there more to the error message? More text to it?

Comment: We have used mfpmigrate cli to migrate the client . The app is hyibrid cordova app with client code with jquery mobile.

Comment: In the MFP console we have created the application for ios and android with correct version and app id. In the device tab of the server we can see the registered device with client id. wondering still why we are getting this error. There is no more error message except this above in the server log

Comment: Uninstall the application on the device , re-install it and then try again. If it still fails, provide the logs from the server